# Select a Builder Image and resource to see if there is a pipeline template available for this runtime

Tags: openshift

I've been doing some exercises in the OpenShift Developer Sandbox.
I was attempting to get a Kafka Cluster in the sandbox, following this tutorial :

[image: Kafka Cluster]

https://medium.com/oracledevs/15-minutes-to-get-a-kafka-cluster-running-on-kubernetes-and-start-producing-and-consuming-from-a-b0fa7f8bcfeb

But when attempting to Clone the following repository :
https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka

I got the error :

"Select a Builder Image and resource to see if there is a pipeline template available for this runtime"

[image: Error_No_Image_Builder]

Now, the error clearly says that there is an issue with selecting the appropriate builder image and resource. But I have no clue on how to select them.

- A friend of mine has been looking at the Yolean github repository that I used https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka
- He believes that I can’t simply paste the url like this, because these contains **deploy settings**, and **not an image** or code
- I will further investigate and read the documentation about permissions and **clusterRoles**. But we both believe that this might well be a sandbox limitation

In case someone has a hint, I would be very grateful.